# Getting the ID of a certain element in JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How could I access the id of the TR/element where the user is in every time I click the .delete button.

```
foreach($devices as $device){ ?>
        <tr id="<?php echo $device['id']; ?>" class="edit_tr">
           <td>
            <input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete" id="delete_<?php echo $device['id']; ?>">
           </td>
</tr>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(".delete").click(function(){
        var ID=$(".edit_tr").attr('id');
```

with my code, ID only returns the first tr ID and not the ID where the user is currently focused at.

Comment: What you want ,are you looking for ,getting the ID of clicked element?

Comment: You need to read up on the jQuery API, specifically, the [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should select the closest `tr` element and then call the `.attr()` method:

```
$(".delete").click(function() {
   var ID = $(this).closest(".edit_tr").attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.delete').click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("delete_",""); 
});
```

Then, you can capture the same id that the tr